# Puzzles + Rebus Equals... Well Rebuses... Also Wordplay: Chemical Compounds (And Biology)

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, rebus

Here are some more rebuses. Some also have some word play! These three are just for people's enjoyment. I will accept partial answers.
[image]

Comment: B is just showing you two different ways to get the same answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A:

> Desoxyribonucleotide (Credit: Jordan.J.D)

B:

> Aqua Regia (lat. aqua = water and rex, regis = king -> crown)/(REGIrock + water)

C:

> Methylenphenidate (Credit: YeetKid)

Comment: Finally! I'd forgotten about this, it's been inactive for so long :P. Yes, b is correct.

Comment: B is actually pretty simple, I put crowns over water symbolizing royalty, and your answer for b literally means "royal water".

Comment: Marking this as accepted, since it was the last one done and all answerers contributed a same amount of partial answers.

Answer (score 7):

A)

> (deoxys) (rib) (nuclear) (water): Deoxyribonucleotide

B)

> (A) = (Regirock) (Crown):

C)

> (Methylene Group) (FEM [(finite element method)](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Finite_element_method_1D_illustration1.png)) (Dates): methylphenidate (YeetKid put it together for me)

Comment: So close!!! But incorrect...

Comment: @North fixed it, did not know Deoxyribonucleotide was a thing.

Comment: It is! +1 nice job :)

Comment: @North how close am I with C? Can't think of much with it

Comment: @Jordan.J.D That water thingy is called *crown*...

Comment: @ABcDexter which one is the water thingy?

Comment: The bouncing water droplet.

Answer (score 4):

A)

> Deoxyribonucleotide (credit Jordan.J.D)

B)

> no clue lol

C)

> methylphenidate

Comment: Nice you got C correct!

Comment: Nice! I had the parts but couldn't put them together.

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

A.

> Deoxyribonucleotide (credit Jordan.J.D)

B.

> 12-crown-4 ether because there are four crowns and the regirock has arms that resemble the shape of the benzene structure, plus, you can give ethers to Pokemon.

C.

> methylphenidate (credit Yeetkid)

Comment: B is incorrect, Im afraid

Comment: @North, would it be 15-crown-5 then? 4x crowns + the water crown?

Comment: No, you are going the wrong way....